# CAD Eagle difference headers

Tags: eaglecad, cad, orcad, header

I am trying to figure out difference between these two header types. One appears larger than the other with names differing by 'RA' at the end.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RA one is probably "Right Angle"... a plug approaches this connector parallel to the board. With a regular header, the plug approaches perpendicular to the board.